# Git commit vanishes after merge

Tags: git, merge

I am running into a strange issue that is causing work to be lost.  A coworker made a commit a few days ago into a remote branch.  Sometime yesterday that remote branch was merged into master.  All the changes from my coworkers one commit were lost.  Normally I'd say it was a bad merge and it just overwrote his changes.  The logs however don't reflect this.  If I check the logs with gitk, I can see commit 3a2b22f (coworkers orginal commit) a good ways down the list, but if I run gitk on the file in question (to check its history) commit 3a2b22f is no where to be seen.  Its as if after the merge the commit ceased to exist in the files history.

The questions are:

1. How on earth did this happen
2. How does one prevent it from happening again?

Comment: Try `git log --all -- filename.txt` or `gitk --all -- filename.txt`. IIRC, by default, it only follows the first parent through merges...

Comment: ok, it shows up in the log with that. Still I have no idea exactly how the changes got overwritten.  Maybe it was a bad merge after all.

Comment: Well, if the change was present in e.g. commit `HEAD~10`, but it isn't in `HEAD`, it would stand to reason that something in between reversed that change. It's quite possible that the merge is where it happened, but that's not the only candidate. `git bisect` with a simple `grep`-based check (or visual inspection of `git log --all -p -- filename.txt`) would be reasonable ways to determine where the change was lost/reverted/reversed/replaced...

Comment: I tried bisect, but I must not be doing it right. bisect start, bisect good 3a2b22f, bisect bad is the latest commit.  Each time changes from 3a2b22f are not present I do a git bisect bad.  The result is git blames a commit made 4 days before 3a2b22f.  gitk --all still looks like its missing a commit.the commit right after 3a2b22f has the regression, but it isn't highlighted in the diff.  Very confusing.

Comment: @twalberg, your gitk --all -- filename.txt did the trick. I didnt look close enough the first time I did it.  It showed me the commit itself was never merged into master to begin with.  If you post your first comment as an answer I'll upvote and credit it to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gitk --all -- filename.txt` to see the entire history of a file so you can figure out where merges happened, etc. A command line equivalent would be `git log --pretty=oneline --graph --all -- filename.txt`.

By default, `gitk` and `git log`, when given a file name to work with, will only follow the first parent at merges. Specifying the `--all` flag causes them to include commits on any branch. `gitk` also has a `--merge` option that may be pertinent here, and of course `git log` has way too many different options to keep track of that can affect which commits are displayed and how the display is done.